# Pandas Data clean up

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import sys
auto = pd.read_csv(
    "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data",
    names=['MPG', 'Cylinders', 'Displacement', 'Horse power',
           'Weight', 'Acceleration', 'Model Year', 'Origin', 'Car Name']
)

auto.head()
```

[image: Out put image]

I need to clean up this data but i keep getting this out put and need a bit of help. Beginner here and i can't figure it out

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the file, the separators are not constant but a variation of spaces. sep = '\s+' is giving the desired output.

```
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data"
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep = '\s+',names = ['MPG','Cylinders','Displacement','Horse power','Weight','Acceleration','Model Year','Origin','Car Name'])
df.head() 


    MPG Cylinders   Displacement    Horse power Weight  Acceleration    Model Year  Origin  Car Name
0   18      8       307             130.0       3504    12.0            70      1   chevrolet chevelle malibu
1   15      8       350             165.0       3693    11.5            70      1   buick skylark 320
2   18      8       318             150.0       3436    11.0            70      1   plymouth satellite
3   16      8       304             150.0       3433    12.0            70      1   amc rebel sst
4   17      8       302             140.0       3449    10.5            70      1   ford torino
```

​

Answer (score 2):

Use `delim_whitespace` argument:

```
url = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.data'
cols = ['MPG', 'Cylinders', 'Displacement', 'Horse power', 'Weight', 
        'Acceleration', 'Model Year', 'Origin', 'Car Name']

auto = pd.read_csv(url, names=cols, delim_whitespace=True)

auto.head()
Out: 
    MPG  Cylinders  Displacement Horse power  Weight  Acceleration  \
0  18.0          8         307.0       130.0  3504.0          12.0   
1  15.0          8         350.0       165.0  3693.0          11.5   
2  18.0          8         318.0       150.0  3436.0          11.0   
3  16.0          8         304.0       150.0  3433.0          12.0   
4  17.0          8         302.0       140.0  3449.0          10.5   

   Model Year  Origin                   Car Name  
0          70       1  chevrolet chevelle malibu  
1          70       1          buick skylark 320  
2          70       1         plymouth satellite  
3          70       1              amc rebel sst  
4          70       1                ford torino
```